# Python - Pause program and send commands possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a way to pause a Python program and be able to send commands from the prompt during the pause before resuming the code ?

The only way I found to do a pause is to ask for a keyboard entry (like press enter for example) but you can't type commands while it's waiting for you to press enter. 
Is there a way to really pause the code? have access to all variables and possibly modify them in the prompt before resuming?

Comment: `pdb.set_trace` is probably what you want.

Comment: If it's not an issue of debugging like @Kevin says, maybe you are looking for an Input loop. which is the same as your 'readline' solution only in a While True: segment with a break operation. Then you can exec() some input and wait for a 'continue' command to break the loop.

Comment: well I have interpolated data that I compare to the original data. But since the interpolation can be bad sometimes I wanted to pause and check the plot to possibly correct the interpolated data to whatever offset may have appeared before continuing to use it.
So far I just set break points in the program and then run it from the start after I did the correction, I just wanted a pause that allows you to make modifications and then keep executing the code where it was paused.

Comment: Well then, have your work done in another thread, testing after each iteration for a pause flag. In your main thread - have an Input loop, on a pause command set the pause flag - go to the exec() mode, until you get a continue command - reset the flag restart the thread.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this for debugging, check out `pdb`, the [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). You can start you script under `pdb`, set a breakpoint on the line you want, and then run your script.

```
python -m pdb script.py
b 15                       # <-- Set breakpoint on line 15
c                          # "continue" -> run your program
# will break on line 15
```

You can then inspect your variables and call functions. Since Python 3.2, you can also use the `interact` command inside `pdb` to get a regular Python shell at the current execution point!

You can also include the following line directly in your program to stop at that line end drop into pdb:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Then you won't even have to use `-m pdb` on the commandline.

Comment: I've found [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) (a graphical debugger) to be a nice tool for debugging too. Completely optional, of course.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that! The world knows Python needs a better console debugger. Wanted to hack on ipdb a bit, but didn't find the time yet.